# MacBook Pro fans are loud after partitioning disk for Boot Camp use

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, dual-boot

After installing Boot Camp on my MacBook Pro 14,1 the fans in my computer started to make loud sounds like squeezing a plastic bottle every time when it runs at high speed.

After sending it to a service center, an engineer told me it is because I partitioned my disk for Boot Camp and because of that it makes it harder for the computer to read the disk, so it needs more energy and this causes the fans to run at higher speeds.

**My question is here:** Is it safe to install Boot Camp (dual boot or triple boot) on my MacBook?

Answer (score 1):

Is it safe? **Yes.**

The 2017 MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2 x Thunderbolt 3 ports) is more than capable of running the latest 64-bit versions of Windows 10 installed with Boot Camp.

Unfortunately it's difficult for anyone here to speculate on what the Engineer meant, except to say that it seems something has been lost in how they've explained it to you.

However, since Boot Camp is provided by Apple and Boot Camp Assistant software is included with macOS, you know it's safe to use.

As for your description of the loud sound the fans are making, it's not clear from your question whether your fans are always loud or only when you're trying to do certain things. However, the first thing I'd try is resetting the System Management Controller (SMC).

**How to reset the SMC on your particular MacBook Pro**

1. Shut down your MacBook Pro
2. For 10 seconds, press and hold at the same time the <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>control</kbd><kbd>option</kbd> keys (on the **left** side of the **built-in** keyboard) ***and*** the <kbd>power button</kbd>
3. After 10 seconds let go of all keys and the power button
4. Turn your MacBook Pro back on with the power button

After your MBP reboots, test to see if the fans are still making the same sound.

Comment: I have already did it , even reinstall macOS. But the problem didn't disappear. Engineer said it is because when I partition my disk, it'll cause the disk inside become more complicated.

Comment: Ok, well, I can’t really comment on what you were told because it doesn’t really make sense. But I can answer the question you asked about whether Boot Camp is safe to install on your MacBook Pro, and it most definitely is. :)